# How to get an overall p-value for an independent categorical variable using generalized estimating equations (geeglm) in R

Tags: r, p-value

I would like to know if there is a way to get an overall p-value for an independent categorical variable using generalized estimating equations in R. When I run the analysis, the output provides p-values for each level of the categorical variable, instead of an overall p-value for the variable itself.

One example of an output is this:

```
install.packages("geepack", dependencies=TRUE)
library(geepack
#some code using geeglm with binomial errors
# Results

Call:
geeglm(formula = modality ~ factor(smoking_status), family = "binomial", 
    data = airleak_cleaned_included, id = as.factor(mrn))

 Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std.err  Wald Pr(>|W|)   
(Intercept)                0.875   0.266 10.82    0.001 **
factor(smoking_status)1   -0.359   0.338  1.13    0.287   
factor(smoking_status)2   -1.099   0.722  2.32    0.128   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation structure = independence 
Estimated Scale Parameters:

            Estimate Std.err
(Intercept)        1  0.0597
Number of clusters:   176  Maximum cluster size: 1
```

Comment: Edit to SO standards. I think this is really a stats question.

Comment: Yes, but its easier to do using score tests rather than Wald tests.  In principle: fit an intercept-only model and save the results in, say, `fit0`.  Then fit your model above above and save the results in, say, `fit1`.  Then call `anova(fit0, fit1)`.  For more details, please ask on StackExchange.  I am voting for migration.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I'm posting an "answer", but I don't really want it considered as such because I don't have much statistical theory behind it.</strike>  With Thomas Lumley's endorsement of this as acceptable practice, I'll consider it an answer.  I can show the mechanics of getting a result using R. I  seconded Limey's vote to migrate to stats.stackexchange.com after I searched that site for an answer to the general question of "how to do a principled model comparison" on GEE modeling results to get "overall significance" estimates from those GEEs. I didn't find what I considered to be a satisfying answer on either SO or CV.com.

This code  installs and loads the R library 'geepack' and then builds 2 models (with one that sets the RHS of a formula to `1` to build a "Null model") based on the example code in `?geeglm` and then runs `anova` on the two models. That package does have an `anova.geeglm` function which I take to imply that the authors think this is valid in at least some situations.

```
install.packages('geepack')
library(geepack)
data(dietox)
dietox$Cu     <- as.factor(dietox$Cu)
mf <- formula(Weight ~ Cu * (Time + I(Time^2) + I(Time^3)))
gee1 <- geeglm(mf, data=dietox, id=Pig, family=poisson("identity"), corstr="ar1")
# warnings noted
gee1
coef(gee1)
vcov(gee1)
summary(gee1)
coef(summary(gee1))

mf2 <- formula(Weight ~ 1)
gee2 <- geeglm(mf2, data=dietox, id=Pig, family=poisson("identity"), corstr="ar1")
# more warnings

methods("anova") # to get available class-specific function names
 [1] anova.coxph*       anova.coxphlist*   anova.geeglm*      anova.glm*         anova.glmlist*     anova.glmmPQL*    
 [7] anova.lm*          anova.lmlist*      anova.loess*       anova.loglm*       anova.mlm*         anova.negbin*     
[13] anova.nls*         anova.polr*        anova.survreg*     anova.survreglist*
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code

anova(gee1,gee2)
#---------------
Analysis of 'Wald statistic' Table

Model 1 Weight ~ Cu * (Time + I(Time^2) + I(Time^3)) 
Model 2 Weight ~ 1
  Df   X2 P(>|Chi|)    
1 11 9327    <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

If this were "regular" regression, I would have confidence that this was a valid approach to model comparison and that a X^2 difference of 9327 between nested models differing by 11 degrees of freedom pointed to a high "statistical significance" and a corresponding low p-value. However, I'm being appropriately modest because this is a statistical area about which I have no experience.

Comment: Yes, that's the right idea.  This isn't an anova in the traditional sense, because it's not based on a likelihood, but it does the tests that the original question wanted. In principle a score test might be easier because you don't need to fit the more-complex model but in practice it actually isn't easier and fitting the model is not a problem. The warnings are because the outcome variable isn't integer, which a Poisson variable would be; you can use `quasipoisson` to silence them.

Comment: @ThomasLumley : Thanks, Thomas. I wasn't familiar with the expression `Analysis of 'Wald statistic' Table` but I guess its being done with  inference based on the usual difference in chisquare-distributed  ( X^2) statistic with the difference in adjusted df.

Comment: No, it's *not* being done with the usual difference in chisquared statistics, which doesn't work in this context. It's based on $(\hat\beta-\beta_0)^TV^{-1}(\hat\beta-\beta_0)$ for the subspace of $\beta$ that is in the larger model but not the smaller one.  It doesn't have the nice property of traditional anova that the test statistics for A vs B and B vs C add to give the statistic for A vs C.

Comment: @ThomasLumley So those beta-hats are vectors and V^-1 is the full variance-covariance matrix? Shouldn’t the the displayed results say something along those lines?

Comment: Not the full covariance matrix, the covariance matrix for the subset being tested. That's the coded message of "Wald Statistic" rather than likelihood ratio